# why iterator.next() returns the same item every time?

Tags: java, iterator, set

I have this code:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        if (failureCountAndDUrls.urls.iterator().hasNext()) {
            P p2 = new P().appendText("First "+min+" of "+failureCountAndDUrls.count+":");
            String id = failureCountAndDUrls.urls.iterator().next();
            }
        }
```

`urls` is a `Set<String>`

and yet `.next();`
returns the same item over and over. Even though there are 7 items

how can iterate all the items correctly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is you're creating a new iterator every time, and each new iterator has the same initial state.

Reuse the iterator instead.

```
Iterator<String> it = failureCountAndDUrls.urls.iterator();
for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        P p2 = new P().appendText("First "+min+" of "+failureCountAndDUrls.count+":");
        String id = it.next();
    }
}
```